# How to get the oEmbed type (audio, video, image etc.)?

Tags: oembed

If I embed something with oEmbed, is there a chance to get the type of the embed (video, audio etc.) ?

If I look at [www.oembed.com](http://www.oembed.com/) I see that in the JSON response there is always the data type.

Any chance to get this without hacking the core?

I don't find any functions, except [`wp_oembed_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get), which seems to only return the *width* and *height*.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you mean this:

```
add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', function( $return, $data, $url )
{
    // Target only 'video' type:
    if(
            is_object( $data ) 
        &&  property_exists( $data, 'type' )
        &&  'video' === $data->type
    )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    return $return;
}, 10, 3 );
```

where we target the `video` type response from the oEmbed service, before it's cached in the post meta.

Comment: Good question, good answer. +1